# Laravel - Define path variable

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

how do I define path variable in laravel? For example, I have a webserver path
`https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/profile_image`

in my HTML I will have:

```
   <img style="width: 100%;padding:1px;border: 2px solid #555" src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/myapps/profile_image/{{ $data->ap_thread_created_by}}/{{ $data->image_path }}">
```

but I wish to get the path in my config or somewhere else.. instead of hardcoding the path.

Comment: Put all your images/css/js in public folder... and then in view you can use {{assets('img/img.jpg')}}

Comment: If you want to use a variable, do it in controller. And access it in view.

Comment: hi, because im using amazon s3 for my image storing, i dun wanna it to be stored under my project folder..
Hi, how do i define it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define environment variable in .env file:

```
IMAGES_PATH=https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/myapps/profile_image
```

And get it in any place this way:

```
<img style="width: 100%;padding:1px;border: 2px solid #555" src="{{env('IMAGES_PATH')}}/{{ $data->ap_thread_created_by}}/{{ $data->image_path }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$data` is representation of your model for example `Photo` you can add [accessor](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) to it:

```
public function getStoragePathAttribute($value) 
{
   return 'https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/myapps/profile_image/';
}
```

and now in your blade you can use:

```
<img style="width: 100%;padding:1px;border: 2px solid #555" src="{{ $data->storage_path }}{{ $data->ap_thread_created_by}}/{{ $data->image_path }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
function avatar_url($data) {
    return "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/myapps/profile_image/{$data->ap_thread_created_by}/{$data->image_path}";
}
// src="{{avatar_url($data)}}"
```